# Edit a remote file in Vim with sudo when ssh root login is disabled

Tags: sudo, vim

I am trying to determine a way to edit remote files in Vim that require sudo, but still use my local vim config and plugins.

Currently I can open `vim` and `:e scp://me@server//some/root/file` and make changes, but when I try to write it, I of course get "permission denied".

If I try the "I forgot sudo" command (`:w !sudo tee %`) it tries to scp the file back as root, which is disabled. I've also tried `ssh -t user@host sudo vim /some/file`, but this does not source any local config.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a method I may have overlooked? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If that's a genuine requirement you might benefit from having your (admin) home directories on a NFS share that gets mounted on demand with the auto mounter. You'll have the same history, aliases and settings on every system you administer. 

In practice I have worked in too many environments and given up relying on anything customised and non-standard, I can get all sysadmin tasks done without relying on such crutches.

Comment: But you could sync your `.vimrc` with [vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh) or similar tools.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just copy your Vim configuration to the remote server, and edit it there? Assuming of course, that Vim and X is installed.

The "rsync" command does a good job of keeping everything consistent, so you can copy your Vim setup everywhere. Ideally you would then log into the remote server, and install your Vim config as root as well. :-)

Example:

```
rsync -avzp ~/.vimrc ~/.vim you@remote-server:~

ssh you@remote-server
sudo rsync -avzp ~you/.vimrc ~you/.vim ~root
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eventually do that from vim, assuming you have sudo access on the remote server:

```
function! WriteRemote()
  let pat = '^scp://\(.\{-}\)/'
  let l = matchlist( bufname('%'), pat)
  if len(l) < 2
    echom "could not get remote host"
    return
  end
  let remote = l[1]
  let temp_file = expand('%:t')
  let dest_file = substitute( bufname('%'), pat, '', '')

  execute "write! scp://" . remote . "//tmp/" . temp_file
  execute "!ssh -t " . remote .
    \ " 'sudo tee >/dev/null -- " . dest_file .
    \ " </tmp/".temp_file .
    \ " ; rm -- /tmp/".temp_file . "'"
endfunction
```

You can just save your remote local buffer using `:execute WriteRemote()`

Be aware that this function has not been tested much. But you've got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite for this way of doing it (using rsync instead of scp):
You must have passwordless `sudo` on the remote machine.

If true, you can:

1.) first change the rsync command in your local vim setup:

```
:let g:netrw_rsync_cmd='rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync"'
```

so on the remotehost "sudo rsync" is executed, not just "rsync" see `:h netrw-externapp`

2.) read the file:
After the hostname you have to write `:/filename` not `//filename` (as usual in vim?!)

```
:e rsync://myhost.net:/etc/apt/sources.list
```

3.) write the file

```
:e rsync://myhost.net:/etc/apt/sources.list
```

x.) to print possible error use:

```
:verbose e rsync://myhost.net:/etc/my_file
```